# SVN Error: org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Are all the targets part of the same working copy?

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, netbeans-7

Trying to make a commit with Netbeans 7.1.2 (Subversion plugin Version: 1.19.5.42.1) i get this error:

org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Are all the targets part of the same working copy?
Unable to lock 'Path of one of my Java packages'.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Which SVN Client version does your plugin use ? In case it uses a version < 1.7, and you have copied some java packages from a different working copy (including the.svn folder from the other WC), you might get that behaviour. Another option would be, that svn can't lock your WC folder because it is already "locked". The Locks are stored locally (.lock or .lck File) and sometimes, the SVN client fails to clean the up. Try "svn cleanup" in your WC. Hope that helps !

Comment: I'm using the subversion plugin for Netbeans, i don't know to which svn version is related... 
I moved to Netbeans 7.2, which has a newer version of that plugin. It solved partially the problem.